# How can we get results of successfully run tests in TestNG even when the run gets terminated abruptly?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, report, testng

I'm pretty new to TestNG hailing from a cucumber background.
In my current project, the jenkins jobs are configured with Maven and TestNG, using java and Selenium for the scripting.

Any job, say with 30 tests, if takes 2hrs to complete, when abruptly terminated due to some reason on the last minute, I do not get results of any tests that were run successfully. Hence forced to run again the entire job.
All I see is the error stack trace and result as:

```
Results :Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I am sure there is a better way of designing this, hoping for better approaches.

1. How can I make sure I do not lose results of the tests that did run successfully(though passed/failed)?
2. Is a test management tool or some entity to store the run time results , a mandatory requirement or TestNG has some provision built-in?

Comment: Just for clarification sake. Abrupt termination means could you explain what is happening in your case.

Comment: Lets say the browser got closed or the machine was shutdown. By abrupt, i mean a cause external to my code base. Or any reason which is making my console output show Tests run:0 though there were few tests that ran successfully.

Comment: In Jenkins we have Build Steps and Post Build Steps, Any publishers like recording the test results will be executed after the Build Steps success or failed or aborted (by user). In your case the thread itself closing or aborting the process, in such case there is no scope of running the publishers.

Comment: Another case if Build steps exited because of time out or any other cause which makes the process to proceed further Publishers section, by that time the report file with executions report should be available so that it can read the report and publishes the test report in Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make sure I do not lose results of the tests that did run successfully(though passed/failed)?

There are usually two ways in which you can build reporting into your TestNG driven tests.

1. Batched mode - This is usually how all the TestNG reports are built. A listener which implements `org.testng.IReporter` interface is built and within its `generateReport()`, all the logic of consolidating the test results into a report is carried out.
2. Realtime mode - This is usually done by implementing the TestNG listener `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener` and then within its `afterInvocation()` do the following :

   - Check the type of the incoming `org.testng.IInvokedMethod` (to see if its a configuration method (or) a `@Test` method ) and handle these types of methods differently (if the report needs to show them separately). Then test the status of `org.testng.ITestResult` and based on the status, show them as `PASS/FAIL/SKIPPED`

`IReporter` implementations are run at the end after all the tests have run (which is why i call them as batched mode). So if something crashes towards the end but before the reporting phase is executed, you lose all execution data.

So you might want to try and build a realtime reporting model. You can take a look at the [RuntimeReporter](https://github.com/paypal/SeLion/blob/develop/client/src/main/java/com/paypal/selion/internal/reports/runtimereport/RuntimeReporterListener.java) report that SeLion uses. Its built on the realtime model.

> Is a test management tool or some entity to store the run time results , a mandatory requirement or TestNG has some provision built-in?

There are no such mandatory requirements that TestNG places. As I explained above, it all boils down to how you are constructing your reports. If you are constructing the reports in a realtime fashion (you can leverage templating engines such as Velocity/Freemarker/Thymeleaf) to build your reporting template and then use the `IInvokedMethodListener` to inject values into the template, so that it can be rendered easily.

Read more [here](https://dzone.com/articles/template-engines-review-after-deprecated-velocity) for a comparison on the templating engines so that you can choose what fits your need.

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, looks like I have found what i wanted, Shall try this out and accept your answer.

Comment: As Krishnan has already given nice and detailed answer , I am not adding another answer here , rather commenting out a bit here . I was facing same issue some time back (Wanted to know which test is being executed in real time on jenkins) . I searched for jenkin plugin and found a plugin called 'Test In Progress Plugin' for jenkins . I configured <listener> tag in my suite.xml and executed build again with updated xml . It started showing real time test execution in separate menu/window on jenkins . I would suggest to try that out and see if it helps .